# What are the standard models of monetary theory?

Tags: inflation, interest-rate, monetary-policy, money-supply

I am currently conducting research on a digital economy which has recently faced inflation issues and thus implemented monetary policy to tackle them. My paper seeks to compare how real life **digital economy** works to **standard models of monetary policy/ inflation/ interest rates/ etc**.

In a nutshell, I want to say where digital economy coincides with theory and where is varies! I'm already looking into quantity theory of money, though I need more economic models/theories.

I am open to any suggestions! Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Basic neoclassical models:

1. Cash-in-Advance
2. Money-in-Utility

Check Walsh’s textbook and Blanchard and Fischer’s textbook for some introductory details.

Comment: Adding to this, OLG models can have monetary equilibrium as well.